# Are these pointer constructions equivalent?

Tags: c++

Are these constructions equivalent?

```
int *(*p[10])() //array of ten pointers onto int functions
```

and

```
int *(*p())[10]
```

Comment: see also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192620/array-of-n-pointers-to-functions-returning-pointers-to-functions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

Here's what the ever-wonderful [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) says:

1. `int *(*p[10])()`: declare `p` as array 10 of pointer to function returning pointer to `int`
2. `int *(*p())[10]`: declare `p` as function returning pointer to array 10 of pointer to `int`.

Intuitively, they "shouldn't" be the same since the declaration syntax of C++ is rarely that ambiguous (at least that's intuitive to me).

It might be worth pointing out that cdecl is also a command-line tool, it's just more convenient to link to the web page hosting an instance of it. Just wanted to make this clear, it's a (very) old tool, I first saw it mentioned in the ["The C Programming Language"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) book by Kernighan and Ritchie, I believe I have the 2nd edition.